# Second derivative test for 2 variable functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am taking my first multivariable calculus course and I came across this second derivative test:

f<sub>xx</sub>f<sub>yy</sub> - f<sub>xy</sub>$^2$

Does that mean that:

1)f<sub>xy</sub> = f<sub>yx</sub>? If that is true, why is that?

2)Can we use f<sub>xx</sub>f<sub>yy</sub> - f<sub>yx</sub>$^2$ instead of f<sub>xx</sub>f<sub>yy</sub> - f<sub>xy</sub>$^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ is true whenever $f$ has continuous second derivatives. In this case it usually goes by the name of Clairaut's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). This hypothesis of continuity of the derivatives is necessary as there are examples of functions whose mixed derivatives are not equal.

In the case where $f$ does indeed have continuous second derivatives then the answer to both of your questions is yes.

Comment: What if it is not know whether second derivatives are continuous?

Comment: In that case you will have no guarantee that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.

Comment: OK. And what about my second question? Is there no guarantee there as well? Intuitively, I thought that we could use fyx instead after seeing the matrix form of this equation.

Comment: I'm not positive, but my general understanding is that the second derivative test works because the Hessian provides a good local estimate of the second order behavior of the function. If second derivatives are not continuous then the Hessian may not be a good local approximation of the second order behavior, so I would guess the test doesn't apply there and there may be cases where you get spurious results. In any case in this setting the correct formula for the discriminant would be $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}$